# Одиночное деепричастие в предложении Стругацких. Пунктуация

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, деепричастия

В сценарии Стругацких "День затмения" ("Дни затмения") есть такое предложение:
*И, однако, что-то там тоже было не в порядке: там, на улице, пронесся вдруг желтый пыльный вихрь, хлопнуло где-то окно, стекла **зазвенели разлетаясь** и раздались какие-то крики — не то отчаянные, не то радостные.*

Мне кажется, пропущена запятая после слова "зазвенели". Но, видимо, нужна и вторая запятая после "разлетаясь".

Какой из вариантов верен? Заранее благодарен за ответы.

Comment: https://old-rozental.online/punctuatio.php?sid=113 Одиночное деепричастие или деепричастный оборот не обособляется:

1) если деепричастный оборот (обычно со значением обстоятельства образа действия) тесно связан по содержанию со сказуемым и образует смысловой центр высказывания: Она сидела чуть откинув голову (Марк.) — указывается, что она не просто сидела, а сидела с откинутой головой;

Comment: @КириллМалышев не скромничайте, сделайте полноценный ответ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Знаки препинания у Стругацких поставлены верно:

*И, однако, что-то там тоже было не в порядке: там, на улице, пронесся вдруг желтый пыльный вИхрь, хлопнуло где-то окнО, **стекла зазвенели разлетАясь** и раздались какие-то крИки — не то отчаянные, не то радостные.*

Почему? Да потому что решать задачу о тесной связи нужно **для конкретного предложения, а не для абстрактной конструкции.** После двоеточия мы имеем 4 однородных предложения с бессоюзной связью (интонация перечислительная),  да еще в конце присоединительная конструкция, обособленная тире. Поэтому ударение в каждом случае  ставится только на одном слове, мы **не можем выделять одно из предложений, добавляя туда обособленный член.**

Отсюда и следует тесная связь деепричастия с глаголом, так как обособлять его здесь неудобно.

Сравнить: *Где-то рядом хлопнуло окнО и стекла **зазвЕнели,  разлетАясь.*** Здесь деепричастие надо обособить.

Answer (score 5):

По смыслу я *не* нахожу здесь ни *тесной связи* (относящиеся к стеклам два действия без изменения смысла могут быть выражены порознь глаголами: *зазвенели*, когда *стали разлетаться*), ни признаков *образа действия*, которые позволяли бы трактовать деепричастие как аналог наречия. Не вижу и прямой аналогии между выражениями "**разлетаться звеня**" (разлетаться со звоном) и "**зазвенеть, разлетаясь**" (зазвенеть, начав разлетаться). На месте корректоров я обязательно поставил бы **две запятые**.

Comment: Форум дружно голосует  за  определенность и однозначность в пунктуации (а ведь Розенталь предупреждал, что не надо так делать).  Технология здесь простая: определяем семантику и сочетаемость слов (в нашем собственном понимании), ставим инвентарный номер и в таком виде рекомендуем для постоянного использования в любых синтаксических конструкциях.  А если писатель с вами не согласен, то это корректоры ошибки пропускают.   По принципу – я  правильно стол собрал, а эти  детали лишние.

Comment: Я приведу простой пример: все знают, что деепричастная форма «не спеша» имеет значения наречия и поэтому не обособляется. По частотности это действительно так, но всё-таки иногда обособление случается, например: 
Готовились, НЕ СПЕША, к выходу пассажиры, проводники разносили билеты, голосило поездное радио.В переулке было пустынно, только немолодой человек с палкой шел, НЕ СПЕША, по своим делам.После этого встречный плюнул под себя, шаркнул, пересёк, НЕ СПЕША, улицу и сказал Юлиану: иди за мной.   Тоже ошибки корректоров?

Comment: Очередной раз цитирую Розенталя: "Если в области орфографии желательна и необходима полная унификация, то к пунктуации это требование неприменимо. Особенности русской пунктуации — в присущей ей многофункциональности знаков препинания и широкой их взаимозаменяемости, в своеобразии индивидуально-авторского использования знаков препинания, в гибкости пунктуационной системы".

Comment: В случае с "не спеша" _возможен_ смысл классического деепричастия. В первом примере порядок слов едва ли не вынуждает такую трактовку: если заменить "не спеша" на "неспешно" (образ действия), то первые два слова оказываются в инверсном порядке, превращая прозу в подобие белого стиха. В примере же из вопроса самой возможности такой трактовки (как наречия) _нет_.

Comment: Это всего лишь пример, не в нем дело, у того же Розенталя приведено много парных вариантов.  Я говорю о том, что не надо рассматривать  конструкцию отдельно от предложения, в котором она используется – вот в чем ваша   ПРИНЦИПИАЛЬНАЯ ОШИБКА.  Извлекаете оборот из его структуры и определяете возможность его обособления в этой структуре?  Напрасный труд, потому что всё зависит от того, как он впишется в интонационно-структурную модель конкретного предложения.

Comment: Я рассмотрел предложенный конкретный случай, не делая обобщений (для вывода по примеру из вопроса достаточно здравого смысла.). "Парность" (как и другие ранее приводившиеся аргументы - только потому упомянуты в ответе) к нему неприменима.

Comment: Жаль, что вы меня не слышите, я всегда считала, что вы мыслите оригинально, нестандартно и способны на какие-то фундаментальные обобщения.В любом случае спасибо за ваше мнение.

Answer (score 2):

[Братья Стругацкие. Дни затмения](https://strugacki.ru/book_15/585.html):

> И, однако, что-то там тоже было не в порядке: там, на улице, пронесся вдруг желтый пыльный вихрь, хлопнуло где-то окно, **стекла зазвенели разлетаясь** и раздались какие-то крики — не то отчаянные, не то радостные.

Одиночное деепричастие "разлетаясь" примыкает непосредственно к сказуемому "зазвенели", не обозначает добавочного действия (тесно связано с глаголом: звенели и разлетались одновременно) и по своему значению приближается к наречию, поэтому запятыми и не выделяется.

*И вот это свершилось... **звеня разлетелись кувшины**, и идет облако света во тьме.*
Н. С. Лесков. Островитяне

В общем случае одиночные деепричастия обособляются.
*За спиной Юрковского зазвенела, разлетаясь, витрина* (Братья Стругацкие. Стажеры).

[Деепричастия и деепричастные обороты](https://dict.nsu.ru/mod/book/view.php?id=12&chapterid=63)

**Дополнение**

Есть [вариант](https://books.google.ee/books?id=yNo4DwAAQBAJ&pg=PT37&lpg=PT37&dq=%D0%98,%20%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE,%20%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BC%20%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%20%D0%B1%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BE%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D0%B2%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%B5:%20%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BC,%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B5,%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D0%B2%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%20%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D0%BF%D1%8B%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%85%D1%80&source=bl&ots=0Euk9UYD6W&sig=ACfU3U1b_y-Qw7PJs1LK5sqwV0xS4eTsLA&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi77ofl2rvsAhVN_SoKHWMTCiMQ6AEwAHoECAIQAg#v=onepage&q=%D0%98%2C%20%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%2C%20%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BC%20%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%20%D0%B1%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BE%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D0%B2%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%B5%3A%20%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BC%2C%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B5%2C%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D0%B2%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%20%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D0%BF%D1%8B%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%85%D1%80&f=false) и с выделением деепричастия — конечно же, с двух сторон.
Сейчас трудно сказать, как в действительности было оформлено предложение у братьев Стругацких — у корректора издательства может быть свое видение, он мог внести свою правку в текст, основываясь на стандартных правилах пунктуации.
Я бы не стала ставить запятые.

Comment: Дело в том, что так написано как минимум в двух изданиях. Казалось бы, дважды ошибиться невозможно. Но я уже не впервые сталкиваюсь с тем, что в разных изданиях текст просто копируется, и, хотя в выходных данных присутствуют фамилии корректоров, одни и те же ошибки повторяются "один в один".

Comment: Бывает, что ошибки или опечатки кочуют из издания в издание.

Answer (score 1):

> Мне кажется, пропущена запятая после слова "зазвенели".

Нет, запятые (обе) вполне возможны, но не обязательны. "Разлетаясь" - одиночное деепричастие, которое можно трактовать как деепричастие в функции образа действия. Они обычно не обособляются. Подробности вам уже дали.

> Но, видимо, нужна и вторая запятая после "разлетаясь".

Вот тут сложнее. Запятая тоже не нужна (если не обособляем деепричастие), но возникает вопрос о независимых предложениях, соединенных союзом "И". Обычно они разделяются запятыми, роме нескольких, особо оговариваемых случаев.

Один из таких случаев - наш.

> В сложносочиненном предложении с одиночными союзами и, да (в значении
> «и»), или, либо запятая не ставится в следующих случаях:
> ...
> 2) если части сложносочиненного предложения имеют общее вводное слово, общий
> обособленный член или общую, поясняемую ими, часть сложного
> предложения: Словом, время уже истекло и пора было уходить; Вопреки
> предсказаниям синоптиков, небо уже прояснилось и дождь перестал; Было
> у Анны необъяснимое ощущение: еще чуть-чуть и вся эта история кончится
> (Щерб.); Останавливаться было нельзя: ноги засасывало и следы
> наливались водой (Пауст.);

https://orfhographia.ru/punctum_uk.php?rid=353